# How ref in useRef works?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref, virtual-dom

Can someone explain some React issues,? How can ref (from useRef, for example ) in component be the same if VirtualDOM creates NEW objects in every rerendering? This means that ref to that object should be differ from the previous one

Answer (score 0):

`ref` is just a wrapper for a **mutable** variable. When passed as prop into component, it will be set to point to the actual DOM element. This DOM element can be swapped on re-render, which will cause that variable to change.

Comment: Thanks! But it's hard for me to understand how can it pointing to the actual  DOM element if it refs to React Component instance. And moreover, how it saves if New instance creating in every rendering?